# Finding trigrams in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find all trigrams in any given text file, however, when I use this code I don't get any error messages, but I don't get the desired trigrams either. It just returns nothing.

Here is the code:

```
import sys

def arg2(pair):
return pair[1]

def getTrigrams(wordList):
trigrams = []
for i in range(len(wordList) - 2):
    trigram = (wordList[i], wordList[i + 1], wordList[i + 2])
    trigrams.append(trigram)
    return trigrams

def main(argv):
if len(argv) > 1:
    for arg in argv[1: ]:
        text = open(arg, "r")
        trigram_dictionary = {}
        content = text.read()
        lines = content.split("\n")
        for line in lines:
              words = [word for word in line.split(" ") if word.isalpha()]
              trigram_list = getTrigrams(words)
              for trigram in trigram_list:
                  if trigram not in trigram_dictionary:
                     trigram_dictionary[trigram] = 1
                  else :
                     trigram_dictionary[trigram] += 1
                     sorted_trigram_frequencies = sorted(trigram_dictionary.items(), 
                     key = arg2, reverse = True)
                     for trigram in sorted_trigram_frequencies:
                         print("{0:20}\t{1:5}".format("\t".join(trigram[0]), trigram[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Just posting the code with a __*very*__ brief explanation of the problem you are facing is not a valid question here.

Comment: There are **countless** posts on how to do `ngrams`  properly in Python...

Comment: Start with some basic debugging. Insert some print statements in various places to check that the state of the program is where you expect it to be at that point. Once you find where something gives an unexpected result, you'll have a better idea where to look for problems. (Also: check your code formatting when you paste it here: all of your functions are improperly indented. That's very important in python.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you need to be very careful of indentation. (also when pasting code to SO)

If you take another look at your code in the `if ... else ...` block near the end of your code, you'll notice that you are only sorting and printing the trigrams if you find a second identical one. This also means that if you have multiple duplicates, you'll print all of your currently found trigrams multiple times.

You should pull your sorting and printing code back 2 or 3 indentation levels.